# How to fit output code of tinymce in my container element?

Tags: html, css

I am using 'tinymce' to output some codes, but the result is overflowing from its main container, like this:

[image]

I tried to solve it using css, so what I did was this

the container that wrapped this code is 'pre.language-markup', so I added the following code:

```
.article-content {   # container of pre.language-markup
  white-space: pre-line;
  position: relative; */
}

pre.language-markup{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

as a result it added some scroll and decreased abit of its width but yet didn't solve the problem,

[image]

I usually use that above code to fit a child element in parent, but how do I do this?
please help me thank you

Comment: What happens when you do `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: Its kinda hard helping you without *actual code*; if you are using absolute and relative positioning all over your site I'm sure you'll be having a hard time; can you replicate this particular issue on a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I've noticed that the article text also overflows the container. I'm assuming that's because the article text is contained in a `pre` whareas I think it should be contained in a `div`, which wrapps its text naturally. So, using a `div` for the article text let's assume that your HTML is something like this:

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="article-content">
      <div class="article-text">
        <ol>
          <li>Really really really really really really really really really long comment.</li>
          <li>Really really really really really really really really really long comment.</li>
          <li>Really really really really really really really really really long comment.</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <pre class="language-markup">
        <p> Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line</p>
        <p> Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line</p>
        <p> Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line</p>
        <p> Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line</p>      
      </pre>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Using some CSS along these lines should do the trick:

```css
.body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.article-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
}

.article-text {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
}

.language-markup {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 80%;
}
```

I've also put together a JSFiddle of this here:https://jsfiddle.net/Lewbnrp6/

Finally, I would also suggest that as a general practice you avoid using `!important` since it's normally used to make sure that a CSS rule is never overridden, and not to impose a certain rule on an element.